# How to fix an overlapping image in CSS?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How do I fix if my image is overlapping a an area of my page? I have an image which should be a part of my navigation bar but what happen is that the image didn't show when I refreshed the page. I'm still learning css so please bear with me.

**HTML**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <!-- Button for smallest screens -->
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
            <!--<a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
            <img src="assets/images/logo.png" alt="Techro HTML5 template"></a>-->
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                <li class="c1 active"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li class="c1"><a href="profile.php">Profile</a></li>
                <li class="c1"><a href="games.php">Games</a></li>
                <li class="c1"><a href="#">Top Players</a></li>                     
                <li class="c1"><a href="about.php">About</a></li>                   
                <li class="c1 dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Settings <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a data-toggle="modal" data-target='#change'>Change Password</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../logout.php">Logout</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>

    <!--MODAL-->
        <?php include("includes/changepass.php");?>
    <!--END MODAL-->

</nav>

<nav class="nav-top"></nav>
```

**CSS**

```
.navbar-inverse {
  background: #ff4e50;  
  margin: 0 auto; 
  border: none;
  z-index: -1;
}
.nav-top{
  background-image: url(../images/header-top.png);
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

**What It looks now**

[image]

**The Image**

[image]

**My Plan**

[image]

Comment: can you add screenshot or demo?

Comment: which image you are talking about.??

Comment: I created this bootply for you still the problem is not clear 
http://www.bootply.com/UTuzsjBxo1

Comment: I added more details above guys

Comment: @KaelJasper, check this https://jsfiddle.net/vw7vssvj/ m not able to see any gap..but in .nav-top there is margin-bottom:40px. you are talking about that?

Comment: @Leothelion No sir, image and the nav bar should be attached. I purposely added a margin bottom so that it wont stick with the black image you see in the "What it looks now".

Comment: then check my fiddle..in that image is attached to nav bar..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The background image isn't showing becase the `nav-top` div hasn't got a height or any content inside of it.

Please check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/phq6q30n/

I've simply added a height to the div as follows:

```
.nav-top{
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/21g76.png);
  height: 200px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

I would experiment with the height property and see what works best for your project.

Comment: yeah, I got it but now it's to big. Thanks btw.

Comment: No problem, glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

By default the nav `class="navbar"` could have negative bottom margin as seen in https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/

Try adding this css rule

```
.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

You might find the "Select an element on the page to inspect it" function in the developer console useful for css issues like this. It's located on the left top corner of the chrome console. Read more here: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/iterate/inspect-styles/basics?hl=en